# threre are four nodes in output layer, but I want to use one of the node' s output, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Code of the output layer:

```
Weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([11, 4]))

biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 4]) + 0.1)
Wx_plus_b1 = tf.matmul(l0, Weights1) + biases1

N1act = 2/(1+pow(math.e,-Wx_plus_b1[3]))-1
```

I want to use output of the fourth node

This is my custom activation function, it only needs one input.

```
prediction = tf_spiky(N1act)
```

Error info:

> raise ValueError(err.message)
>
> ValueError: slice index 3 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for
>   'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [1,4], [1],
>   [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = , input[2] = ,
>   input[3] = .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `tf.matmul(l0, Weights1)` and `biases1` has shape [1,4], and consequently so does `Wx_plus_b1`. That is, `Wx_plus_b1` is a matrix with one row and four columns. When you write `Wx_plus_b1[3]` you are selecting row number 4 of `Wx_plus_b1` which does not exist, hence the error. The value you are looking for is actually `Wx_plus_b1[0,3]`, i.e. the value in the fourth column of the first row.

Comment: thank you for your answer，but your method doesn't work. I changed Wx_plus_b1[3] into Wx_plus_b1[0,3], then an error emerge, which is Expected binary or unicode string, got <tf.Tensor 'add_46:0' shape=(1, 4) dtype=float32>

Comment: I tried to tf.split the tensor, but the same error emerged, which is Expected binary or unicode string, got <tf.Tensor 'add_46:0' shape=(1, 4) dtype=float32> , it seems that the tf.spilt didn't split the tensor

Comment: It seems to be another error. What happens if you eliminate Wx_plus_b1[3] and its variations altogether? E.g. set N1act = 2/(1+pow(math.e,1))-1 or N1act = 1 and see if you still get an error. Based on the error message my guess is that N1act is correct and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Set N1act = 2/(1+pow(math.e,1))-1 or N1act = 1 will lead to the error that No gradients provided for any variable, and if I change the number of the output  from 4 into 1, the network can run perfectly. So I think the source of the problem is that I did not split the tensor successfully.